# unicode error when importing in python3

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, unicode, syntax-error, python-import

I'm trying to import pandas_datareader.data to use DataReader, but it keeps return a unicode error like this:

```
In[38]: import pandas_datareader.data
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mone\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3066, in run_code
exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-38-8725a3b77af5>", line 1, in <module>
import pandas_datareader.data
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2016.2.3\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\mone\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\data.py", line 7, in <module>
from pandas_datareader.google.daily import GoogleDailyReader
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2016.2.3\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\mone\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\google\daily.py", line 1, in <module>
from pandas_datareader.base import _DailyBaseReader
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2016.2.3\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\mone\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\base.py", line 3, in <module>
import numpy as np
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2016.2.3\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\mone\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 126, in <module>
from numpy.__config__ import show as show_config
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2016.2.3\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\mone\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\__config__.py", line 5
lapack_opt_info={'define_macros': [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)], 'libraries': ['mkl_core_dll', 'mkl_intel_c_dll', 'mkl_intel_thread_dll'], 'library_dirs': ['C:\Users\mone\Anaconda3\\Library\\lib'], 'include_dirs': ['C:\Users\mone\Anaconda3\\Library\\include']}
                                                                                                                                                                           ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

I just simply typed

```
In[38]: import pandas_datareader.data
```

in the Python Console in Pycharm.

It seems like '\U' part of 'C:\Users...' is a problem, but there's nothing I can do with it like doubling back slashes or whatever.

this error happens not just for this case, but also for many others.

funny thing is that importing just 'pandas_datareader' works.

any solutions?

Comment: Sounds like a broken NumPy build.

Comment: you were right! I re-intalled numpy, and found that numexpr was also broken so re-installed it too. now it works fine. thank you so much!

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Any one please post it as an answer. It would help someone.